# Can this query explained please?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, case, correlated-subquery

I have a table where n is the node and p is the parent of the node. I need to find which is the parent, inner and leaf. Parent is the parent of all if P in NULL. Inner is the parent of atleast one leaf and leaf has nothing.

```
 n    | p    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    3 |    2 |
|    6 |    8 |
|    9 |    8 |
|    2 |    5 |
|    8 |    5 |
|    5 | NULL |
+------+------+
```

The table is listed above. I dont understand how this query works.

```
SELECT N, IF(P IS NULL,'Root',IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P=B.N)>0,'Inner','Leaf')) FROM BST AS B ORDER BY N;
```

Here the part I could not understand is P=B.N. When I execute this query alone it shows count as zero but when I execute this whole query answer is correct. Please Can someone illustrate how this query works with values taken from this above table as an example. Thanks in advance

The answer for this query is

```
 N    | asnwer |
+------+--------+
|    1 | Leaf   |
|    2 | Inner  |
|    3 | Leaf   |
|    5 | Root   |
|    6 | Leaf   |
|    8 | Inner  |
|    9 | Leaf   |
+------+--------+
```

In the above query P=B.N there is no value for eg., the first value of P is 2 and the first value of N is 1. Both are not equal and throughout the table no value of P is equal to N. Then How the result set is correct. Please explain

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of the 'correlated subquery'

Comment: Just I know what is meant by that correlated subquery. Can you please explain it because I have no idea about how it works. Just saw the structure of the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `CASE` expressions over the function `IF()`:

```
SELECT N, 
       CASE 
         WHEN P IS NULL THEN 'Root'
         ELSE CASE
           WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST AS BB WHERE BB.P = B.N) = 0 THEN 'Leaf'
           ELSE 'Inner'
         END
       END
FROM BST AS B 
ORDER BY N;
```

I changed the condition to check first to `=` instead of `>`.
I also use an alias `BB` for the table inside the correlated subquery just to get the idea that this is not the original queried table but another *copy* of the table.

For every row of the table, the column `P` is checked if it is `null`.
If it is `null` then the result is of course `'Root'`.

If it is not `null` then what must be checked is the number of rows in the table where the value of the column `N` of the table (this is what `B.N` represents) is equal to the column `P` (this is what `BB.P` represents).

In order to get this result what is needed is another *copy* of the table where the counting is done.
If the result is equal to `0` this means that there are not any rows of the table that have as parent that `N` (`B.N`) so the result is `'Leaf'`.
In any other case the result is `'Inner'`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `case` expression with `exists`:

```
select b.*,
       (case when b.p is null then 'parent'
             when exists (select 1 from bst b2 where b2.p = b.n) then 'inner'
             else 'leaf'
        end) as node_type
from bst b;
```

The `exists` is simply checking if another node exists whose parent is this node.  The `where` clause is a correlation clause.  You will note that in this version, *all* columns are qualified with the table aliases, so it is quite clear what columns are referring to which tables.

In this context, `exists` is more efficient than `count()` because `exists` can stop at the first matching value.